# Drop-down menu click outside submenu hide doesnt work with my type of menu (Please read first)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think because i use `type=checkbox`

```
 <ul id="menutaal">
      <li class="main-menu">
        <input class="menuinput" id="check01" type="checkbox" name="menu"/>
        <label class="menulabel"for="check01"><img id="english2" src="images/english.png"></label>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="submenu"><a href="javascript:;" onclick='messageOn()'><img id="spanish2" src="images/spanish.png"></a></li>
          <li class="submenu"><a href="javascript:;" onclick='messageOn1()'><img id="dutch2" src="images/dutch.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
        </ul>
```

When i use the typical fix-codes it hides the submenu but it doesn't go on off-mode, so when i click the menu again nothing happens, and then it works but when i click outside submenu and in the menu again it shows no submenu.

The CSS is:

```
ul#menutaal{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 9.5vw;
    max-width: 9.5vw;

  margin-top:1vh;
  padding:0 0px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
  color: #eee;
    right:0;

}

ul#menutaal > li{

  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;


}

.menulabel{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  padding:0;
    width:9vw;
    height:9vh;
    max-height:7vh;
  line-height:3em;
  transition:background 0.3s;
  cursor:pointer;
    max-width:9vw;

}

.menulabel:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:4.85vh;
  right:0.2vw;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-top:0.28vw solid black;
  border-bottom:0 solid black;
  border-left:0.28vw solid transparent;
  border-right:0.28vw solid transparent;
  transition:border-bottom .1s, border-top .1s .1s;

  }

.menulabel:hover,
input:checked ~ label{background:rgba(212,212,212,0.4);
border-radius:5% 5% 0% 0%;}

input:checked ~ label:after{
  border-top:0 solid black;
  border-bottom:0.28vw solid black;
  transition:border-top .1s, border-bottom .1s .1s;
}


.menuinput{display:none}



    input:checked ~ ul.submenu{
  max-height:20vh;
  transition:max-height 0.3s ease-in;
}


ul.submenu{
  max-height:0%;
margin-left:0.1vw;
    border-radius:0% 0% 5% 5%;
  padding:0;
    width:8.8vw;
    max-width:8.8vw;
  overflow:hidden;
  list-style-type:none;
  background:rgba(236,236,236,1);
  box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transition:max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  position:absolute;
  min-width:0vw;
    z-index:99999;
}

ul.submenu li a{
  display:block;
 height:5.8vh;
  color:#ddd;
  text-decoration:none;
  box-shadow:0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
  transition:background .3s;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

ul.submenu li a:hover{
  background:rgba(117, 161, 221, 0.8);
}
```

I was busy for 8 hours and it drove me crazy, then i slept and when i woke up i posted this question.

Can everyone please not down-vote my question because i think, i am almost sure that my problem is different then the other ten questions asked.

I hope that someone can help me to make the submenu not `hidden` but to let the submenu go up again when you click on `html` as if you click the menu button again when it needs to go up. So that the action is the same as clicking on html like it has an action if you click on "off" menu.

I tried:

```
$('#menutaal').click(function(e){
   $('#menutaal').hide();
})
$('#menutaal').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

To test if `e.stopPropagation` works but it doesn't. Because `e.stopPropagation` should prevent that `#menutaal` hides right?

I tried really everything on asked questions that's why i am writing this.

Help is really really appreciated.

Comment: "Drop-down menu click outside div", "When i use the typical fix-codes it hides the div" What `div` are you talking about? There is no `div` in your code...

Comment: @Sébastien Your right i made a mistake there, it's about `<ul class="submenu">` But it's not enough to only hide it because then the button stay's open and you have to click 2 times before the menu opens again `#menutaal`. Can you please help? I have been trying a half day to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guuess you need to capture the click event on the whole document:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    $('#check01').prop('checked', false);
});
```

you also need to stop propagation when the click occurs on the menu

```
$('#menutaal').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```js
$('#menutaal').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(event) {
  $('#check01').prop('checked', false);
});

function messageOn() {
  console.log('messageOn');
}

function messageOn1() {
  console.log('messageOn1');
}
```

```css
ul#menutaal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 1vh;
  padding: 0 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  color: #f00;
}

ul#menutaal>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menulabel {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 9vw;
  height: 9vh;
  max-height: 7vh;
  line-height: 3em;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 9vw;
}

.menulabel:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 4.85vh;
  right: 0.2vw;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 0.28vw solid black;
  border-bottom: 0 solid black;
  border-left: 0.28vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 0.28vw solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom .1s, border-top .1s .1s;
}

.menulabel:hover,
input:checked~label {
  background: rgba(212, 212, 212, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5% 5% 0% 0%;
}

input:checked~label:after {
  border-top: 0 solid black;
  border-bottom: 0.28vw solid black;
  transition: border-top .1s, border-bottom .1s .1s;
}

.menuinput {
  display: none
}

input:checked~ul.submenu {
  max-height: 20vh;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
}

ul.submenu {
  max-height: 0%;
  margin-left: 0.1vw;
  border-radius: 0% 0% 5% 5%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 8.8vw;
  max-width: 8.8vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: rgba(236, 236, 236, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 0vw;
  z-index: 99999;
}

ul.submenu li a {
  display: block;
  height: 5.8vh;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  transition: background .3s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.submenu li a:hover {
  background: rgba(117, 161, 221, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menutaal">
  <li class="main-menu">
    <input class="menuinput" id="check01" type="checkbox" name="menu" />
    <label class="menulabel" for="check01">ENGLISH</label>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="submenu">
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick='messageOn()'>SPANISH</a>
      </li>
      <li class="submenu">
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick='messageOn1()'>DUTCH</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I hate that it doesn't even open up now. It's like `$('#menutaal').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();` doesn't work in my stylesheet. Can you check it at www.gester.nl/contact-eng (code only on that page).I left the code on top in the html script. I am gonna sleep now and i hope you can find a solution so i can wake up wih a smile tomorrow haha. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: It works, i had to change the order of things. Thanks!